# How to make "Show" function display images with original size?

Tags: image

```
h = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}];
Grid[{{Show[h], 
   Show[h, Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[h]*2}]], 
    PlotRange -> All]}}]
```

The second image is much smaller than the first. I want those two images to have same sizes.

**Attempt 1**

```
h=ExampleData[{"TestImage","House"}];
hDim=ImageDimensions[h];
a=Grid[{{Show[h,PlotRange->hDim],Show[h,Graphics[Line[{{0,0},hDim*2}]],PlotRange->All]}}]
```

[image]

Basically, it works. But the size of two images are still slightly different. Besides, it seems that I can not control the size any more, like use ImageSize.

Comment: remove `PlotRange-> All` and check

Comment: But then I can not see the entire line.

Comment: `Grid[{{Show[h, PlotRange -> ImageDimensions[h]], 
   Show[h, Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[h]*2}]], 
    PlotRange -> All]}}]`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it still not perfect. And this problem looks like an easy one. But I still can not find a perfect solution after couples of hours struggling.

Comment: `Grid[{{Show[h, PlotRange -> hDim], 
   Show[h, Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, hDim*2}]], PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
    PlotRange -> All]}}]`?

Comment: No, there still has a several-pixel difference by exported result. But it is better and acceptable. However, I still can not change the overall display size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the new in M8 [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize) syntax to do this:

```
h = ExampleData[{"TestImage","House"}];
hDim = ImageDimensions[h];
a = Grid[
    {{
        Show[h, ImageSize->hDim->200],
        Show[h, Graphics[Line[{{0,0}, hDim*2}]], ImageSize->hDim->200,
            ImagePadding->0, PlotRangePadding->0, PlotRange->All
        ]
    }},
    Alignment->Bottom
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for not voting due to my low reputation.

Answer (score 1):

We can take control of the image size with `ImagePad` to resize the images and with the `ImageSize ->` option of the `Show` command.  Here is some code that illustrates the approach.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

h = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}];
{wd, ht} = ImageDimensions[h];

imgLeft = ImagePad[h, {{0, 0}, {0, ht}}, White];
sizeLeft = ImageDimensions[imgLeft];

imgRight = ImagePad[h, {{0, wd}, {0, ht}}, White];
sizeRight = ImageDimensions[imgRight];

line = Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[imgRight]}]}];
m = 1/2;

Grid[{{
   Show[imgLeft, ImageSize -> m*sizeLeft],
   Show[{imgRight, line}, ImageSize -> m*sizeRight]}},
 Alignment -> {{Left, Left}, {Bottom}},
 Frame -> All]
```

[image: Side-by-side images]

We use the `Frame -> All` option initially to see the image spacing, borders, etc, and remove it later.

To create the images at the same scale, we first note that the diagonal line is the diagonal of an image that is twice as large as the original.  Knowing that, we pad the original to be the same width and height as the line to obtain an image for the right panel.  Padding does not distort the original.  For the left image we pad the original to the same height as right image.  The padding is only applied to the right and at the top of the original.

We can introduce a "magnification factor", $m$, to control the overall size of the images.  The magnification is applied in the `ImageSize ->` option of the `Show` commands.

Note that the `GraphicsGrid` command is similar to `Grid` command but seems to introduce additional, unwanted padding.